# Using the XamlRenderingBackgroundTask to render an image that is not in the visual tree

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to use the following code, on an image that is not in the visual tree:

```
    public async Task<CanvasBitmap> RenderImage()
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = _p._img;

        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await rtb.RenderAsync(img);
        IBuffer buf = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
        SoftwareBitmap sb = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(buf, BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16, (int)_p._width, (int)_p._height);
        CanvasBitmap cb = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap(_p._resCreator, sb);

        return cb;
    }
```

Which gives me an error, which I believe to be caused because the `Image` does not exist in the visual tree.  After doing some research, I came to the conclusion that using [XamlRenderingBackgroundTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask) would allow me to get around this.  However, this seems to give the same error.

Am I correct in my assumption that this will allow me to render an image that is not in the visual tree (the help file does seem to imply otherwise) and, if not, is there another method to perform this kind of task without adding the image to the page?

Comment: "Gives me an error" - which one?

Comment: It gives a parameter out of range exception, but it is caused by the object not being in the visual tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem. The only way I managed to solve it is by adding the element to the visual tree and then remove it.
Take a look at this [RenderTargetBitmap in Windows Phone Unit Test App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889152/rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-phone-unit-test-app)